# How to pass decimal value to a stored procedure from textbox

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, decimal

I entered the decimal values in the textbox, i want to send the values entered in the textbox to stored procedure to get updated in the appropriate table.

Below is the code of mine,

```
updtstmt.Update_tbl(UserID, No, Convert.ToDecimal(txtQty.Text));

public int Update_tbl(string UserID, string Number, decimal strQuantity)

SqlParameter paraQuantity = new SqlParameter("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18);
```

I want to pass the decimal values from txtQty.Text.

I am getting error as

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

is it right to use Convert.ToDecimal to convert the values from textbox to decimal?

Thanks in advance

Comment: search in google `Input string was not in a correct format.` and there are many SO posts about this. anyway i suggest you use `TryParse`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually "Input string was not in a correct format" occurs when you try to convert string that is not a numeric value. Make sure to check for empty string in your text box.

Something like here:

```
updtstmt.Update_tbl(UserID, No, Convert.ToDecimal(txtQty.Text=="" ? "0.00" : txtQty.Text));
```